# How to render an Image in react which is coming from Nodejs backend as res.json()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

So I'm getting the image data from NodeJs backend whose response from axios in the React frontend is as follows :::

```
data: [239, 191, 189, 239, 191, 189, 239, 191, 189, 239, 191, 189, 0, 16, 74, 70, 73, 70, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1,…]
type: "Buffer"
```

Now I'm setting the state in react component as

```
const buffered = fileResponse.data;
const based64 = new Buffer.from(buffered).toString('base64');
this.setState({ fileData : based64 })
```

After setting the state I'm rendering the image as follows :::

```
<img src={`data:image/jpeg;base64,${this.state.fileData}`} 
     alt=" Not loaded" 
     onLoad = {this.loading}
     onError = {(error) => this.ImgError(error)}
/>
```

While rendering an icon this procedure works fine. The icon gets rendered on the screen and the onLoad event is fired.
But when rendering a jpeg image, the **onError** method always gets fired and the image from the backend never gets rendered on the application just the alt tags get loaded.
Am I doing something wrong in the code above?
I've tried to just use new Buffer() method instead of new Buffer.from(), which gives the same error. I've also tried to lazy load the image using react-lazyload and react-lazy-load-image-component library which produces the same error.Thank you for the help in advance.

**Updated :** This is the function which gets the error :

```
ImgError = (error) => {
        console.log("on Error in image \n\n",error);
        console.log("1.",error.bubbles)
        console.log("2.",error.cancelable)
        console.log("3.",error.currentTarget)
        console.log("4.",error.defaultPrevented)
        console.log("5.",error.dispatchConfig)
        console.log("6.",error.eventPhase)
        console.log("7.",error.isDefaultPrevented)
        console.log("8.",error.isPropogationStopped)
        console.log("9.",error.isTrusted)
        console.log("10.",error.nativeEvent)
        console.log("11.",error.target)
        console.log("12.",error.timeStamp)
        console.log("13.",error.type)

    }
```

and the result to this is

[image]

Comment: What's the actual error returned from the image `onError` callback? Are you sure it's an `image/jpeg` and not `image/png` or other?

Comment: Yes it is a jpeg image, and the error is  on Error in image 

 SyntheticEvent {dispatchConfig: {…}, _targetInst: FiberNode, _dispatchListeners: ƒ, _dispatchInstances: FiberNode, nativeEvent: Event, …}

Comment: Edit your post: Don't add these things in the comments. It's completely unreadable

Comment: @FrankerZ I have edited the post just hadn't deleted the comments.

Answer (score 0):

The `Buffer` API is part of node and it won't work on the browser unless you use an external library like [this one](https://github.com/feross/buffer). I will assume that you are already using it :-)

The following line is not correct:

```js
const based64 = new Buffer.from(buffered).toString('base64');
```

You should be doing this instead:

```js
const based64 = Buffer.from(buffered).toString('base64');
```

Comment: Wouldn't the frontend post an error if I haven't explicitly added buffer using npm install?

Answer (score 0):

In the initial state the fileData value is undefined, so onError is being fired. Make it such that you get a valid src value

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onerror.asp

Comment: I tried that if(this.state.fileData) {
                    return (
                    
                        <img src={`data:image/jpeg;base64,${this.state.fileData}`} 
                            alt=" Not loaded" 
                            onLoad = {this.loading}
                            onError = {(error) => this.ImgError(error)}
                            
                        />
                        
                    )
                }